# Using Open Graph Beta, how do you post that two Facebook users are friends within in an app?

Tags: feed, ticker, facebook-timeline, open-graph-beta

In our app, you can be friends with each other (just like you can be friends on Facebook).

Is it possible to use the Open Graph Beta to post an update in the News Feed, Ticker, and Timeline that a user (who is already authenticated with "Add to Timeline") has "become friends" (action) with another user (object)? It doesn't appear that you can access Facebook profiles as objects, so how would this be accomplished? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could only post that as a normal status update or graph activity feed with hard coded text "John is now friends with Nathan".  The Graph API does not currently allow you to tag users so that the posts could be linked to the user account.